# Find the solution for given PDE along unit circle

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

The problem assigned to me is:

> For the equation
> $$u_x^2 + u_y^2 = u^2$$
> Find the solution when $u|_\Gamma$ = 1, where $\Gamma$ is unit circle at origin.

I was taught about method of characteristics so I tried to write characteristic equations as:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= 2p\\
\frac{dy}{dt} &= 2q\\
\frac{dz}{dt} &= 2z^2\\
\frac{dp}{dt} &= 2pz\\
\frac{dq}{dt} &= 2qz\\
\end{align}$$

I'm having a doubt here. Like why $\frac{dp}{dt}$ and $\frac{dq}{dt}$ aren't zero? They are supposed to be zero since we are considering them on characteristic curves right?

They being non-zero is making me wonder what impact does it have on the solution of given problem?

Answer (score 2):

By the symmetry of the problem, your solution will be radial. Let
$$
v(r)=u(x,y),\qquad r^2=x^2+y^2.
$$
The left hand side of your equation is the square of the gradient, which is nothing but $(v')^2$. So you have
$$
(v')^2=v^2
$$
or $v'=\pm v$, with $v(1)=1$. You get two exponential solutions
$$
v(r)= e^{\pm(r-1)}.
$$
In terms of $(x,y)$,
$$
u(x,y)= e^{\pm(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-1)}.
$$

Comment: @Gonçalo You are right, I was rushing.. Thank you!